# How to make a textbox visible if last item in a combobox is selected c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have combobox9 ,textBox4 and textBox15 in a winform. By default , textBox15 is hidden .

What i'm trying to do.

If textbox4 backcolor is red and the last item in combobox9 is selected , then show textbox15 .

```
         if (comboBox9.SelectedIndex == comboBox9.Items.Count - 1  && textBox4.BackColor == Color.Red) ;

            {
                textBox15.Visible = true;

                textBox15.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

            
            else
            {

                textBox15.Visible = false;
            }
```

No errors, it just doesn't work as expected. It keeps the textbox hidden even when the conditions are satisfied. Any leads?

Comment: Where your code put in? comboBox event?

Comment: Yes ,comboBox9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Did you add break point to check if the code executed? If not executed, you need to subscribe to the event like `comboBox9.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox9_SelectedIndexChanged;`

Comment: @KevinGichia Have you tried debugging the code by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: I honestly don't know why it wasn't working ,looked okay to me . 

I deleted the entire if else block , rewrote it again and it worked ! 

Probably a problem with Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your code in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your combobox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == comboBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's already inside the private void comboBox9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @KevinGichia I think your problem is on your other condition which is for the backcolor of your textbox

Comment: I think it was a problem with visual studio , I deleted the block , rewrote it and it worked